# Issues with formula not outputting the correct/desire date. My weeks start on Saturdays and finish on Fridays

Tags: date, google-sheets, formatting

Using a formula, I would like to determine the next following Friday from a given date. I have an issue where Saturdays (all) are being given an output of the previous Fridays, for instance:

Column A                             Column H
(formula)                          (Date entered)

21/04/2023 (incorrect)               22/04/2023
28/04/2023 (correct)                 23/04/2023

Both in column A should be outputting 28/04/2023

The formula I'm using is:

=IF(H3986="","",(H3986+(6-WEEKDAY(H3986))))

Both cells are formatted the same (Date)

Thanks in advance,
Jose

I tried a variety of formulas, trying different ending and modifications such as:

`IF(H3989="","",(H3989+7-WEEKDAY(H3989))) IF(H3989="","",(H3989+(6-WEEKDAY(H3989, 2)))) IF(H3989="","",(H3989+(5-WEEKDAY(H3989, 16)))) IF(H3989="","",(H3989+(5-WEEKDAY(H3989, 2))))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach you can test out:

```
=xlookup(weekday(H2),sequence(7),{sequence(5,1,5,-1);7;6})+H2
```

[image]

***Updated formula*** (`for current friday to show the same and not the following one`):

```
=xlookup(weekday(H2),sequence(7),{sequence(5,1,5,-1);0;6})+H2
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried and it worked, it showed me 28/04/2023 (the result I was after. However, If I change the date on Column H to 21/04/2023 it should show me 22/04/2023, since that's the following Friday. the result I get from your suggestion is 28/04/2023.
Many thanks for your prompt reply :)

Comment: Isnt 22-April-23 `Saturday`? Your question states `I would like to determine the next following Friday from a given date`

Comment: That's correct, apologised if I made it a bit confusing. 
for example:
Any days from Saturday to Friday, I need a cell that shows that Friday.
20/04/2023 = 21/04/2023
21/04/2023 = 21/04/2023
22/04/2023 = 28/04/2023 -> a new week starts
23/04/2023 = 28/04/2023
and so on..

Comment: try the updated formula added in the answer section.

Comment: That did the trick! what a legend!! thank you so much. I was going insane why Saturdays where not counted towards the current/following week period. Dont quite get why it goes to the Friday that has just passed... anyways, thank you!